# GridBagLayout JLabels & JTextAreas organization within JPanel

Tags: java, layout, grid, jlabel, jtextarea

I'm trying to make 4 columns within a panel.

```
                    JLabel(Title)  
     JLabel                            JLabel
JLabel    JTextArea               JLabel    JTextArea
...
...
...
                      JButton
```

Its pretty much a panel where you enter data. The labels will be something like "speed" then you type in a number in the text area next to it. I'm having a problem with the gridbaglayout though. The title is pretty big so it looks something like this. Using GridBagLayout , The title is at (1,0) but seeing as its so big, when I put the JLabel1 (0,1) and JLabel2 (2,0), they are way too spaced out since the title seems to have taken a pretty big chunk.

```
                       JLabel(Title..............)     

               JLabel1                            JLabel2
               ...
               ...
               ...
                               JButton
```

I want it to be more like

```
            JLabel(Title..........................................)     

                     JLabel                         JLabel
                JLabel  JTextArea              JLabel  JTextArea
            ...
            ...
            ...
                                   JButton
```

The code if you'd like to run it:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }

    JFrame go = new JFrame("Example");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton Button = new JButton("Button");
    GridBagLayout Grid = new GridBagLayout();
    JLabel Title = new JLabel("LARGEE TITLEE");
    JLabel Label1 = new JLabel("Label 1");
    JLabel Label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");

    public Example() {
    panel.setLayout(Grid);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    Title.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 60));

    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
    c.gridy = 0; c.gridx = 1;
    panel.add(Title, c);
    c.gridy = 1; c.gridx = 0;
    panel.add(Label1 , c);
    c.gridx = 2;
    panel.add(Label2, c);
    c.gridy = 2; c.gridx = 1;
    panel.add(Button, c);
    go.add(panel);
    go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    go.setSize(750, 750);
    go.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. Many times, just creating the example will reveal the problem.

Comment: @splungebob I'm pretty sure I've found the problem. I just don't know how to fix it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the screen into parts and specify the width of every component (gridwidth), as well as the gridx and gridy, so that they will be placed accordingly.

The output of the sample I wrote looks like this:

[image]

### Code:

```
public class Example extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }

    JFrame go = new JFrame("Example");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    GridBagLayout Grid = new GridBagLayout();
    JLabel Title = new JLabel("LARGE TITLE", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    JLabel Label1 = new JLabel("Label 1", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    JLabel Label2 = new JLabel("Label 2", SwingConstants.CENTER);


    JLabel anotherLabel1 = new JLabel("Another Label 1", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    JLabel anotherLabel2 = new JLabel("Another Label 2", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea("TextArea 1");
    JTextArea textArea2 = new JTextArea("TextArea 2");

    public Example() {
        panel.setLayout(Grid);
        panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        Title.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 60));

        JButton button;
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 40; //increase height of the title
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(Title, c);

        c.ipady = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(Label1, c);

        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(Label2, c);

        c.ipady = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.weightx = 0.25;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(anotherLabel1, c);

        c.weightx = 0.25;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(textArea1, c);

        c.weightx = 0.25;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(anotherLabel2, c);

        c.weightx = 0.25;
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(textArea2, c);

        button = new JButton("JButton");
        c.ipady = 0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0); 
        c.gridx = 1; 
        c.gridwidth = 2; 
        c.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(button, c);

        go.add(panel);
        go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        go.pack();
        go.setSize(750, 300);
        go.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

### Related Documentation:

- [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: Why do you `panel.setLayout(Gird)` and then soon after `panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout() )` .Won't the second layout override the first one?

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, what you need is to set the title label full width, try this:

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
c.gridwidth = 4; //where 4 is the numbers of columns
c.gridx=0; // set position at (0,0) because now is full width
panel.add(title, c);
```

Comment: I tried that but now no matter what x values my labels are on, they stay clumped up to the far left, right under the beginning of the title.